# Can't Delete Image Stored in AWS S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I'm currently able to upload an image to AWS S3 in my React application but am having trouble deleting the image (deleting from the bucket).

When I upload and display the image, the fetch request comes from 
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/PhotoNew.jpg

When I try to delete the image, the fetch request is made to
https://mybucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/photos/PhotoNew.jpg

The image is not being removed from the bucket.

My functions are currently as follows:

// App.js

```
const config = {
    bucketName: 'mybucket', // name of the bucket
    dirName: 'photos', /* optional */
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxx',
    secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxx',
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state ={
      url: u,
    }
    this.upload = this.upload.bind(this);
    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
  }

  // works correctly
  upload(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    S3FileUpload.uploadFile(file, config)
      .then(data => this.setState({url: data.location}))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  delete(e) {
    const filename = "PhotoNew.jpg";
    S3FileUpload
    .deleteFile(filename, config)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }


  render() {


    return ( <div>
      Upload AWS S3
      <input 
        type="file"
        onChange={this.upload}
      />
      <button onClick={this.delete}>Delete</button>
      <img src={this.state.url} />
    </div>);
  }
}
```

UPDATE

CORS config for S3 bucket.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>localhost:*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: what's your IAM policy for the user which is tied to the `accessKeyId`?

Comment: Not sure.  Can you tell me how to find it?
I've made the bucket publicly accessible in every way possible.
I'm getting a 404 when fetching (https://mybucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/photos/PhotoNew.jpg) on delete. I  think the problem is that it's not finding it, not a permission error.

Comment: in the AWS console > IAM > Users > search for users with `accessKeyId` that you use in your code. List the user's permissions in your question. It might be because the user does not have any permission to delete the object in your bucket.

Comment: oh, can you verify that the file exists in `/mybucket/photos/PhotoNew.jpg`?

Comment: Photo still exists.  Administrator access is granted.

Comment: hmmmm can it be because of the file name? are you using the filename in your question or it has another name? Spaces may play a part in the 404 error. Probably the best way to check is if you can access the file via URL

Comment: I believe it's because the URL is different when I make a delete request but I don't understand why it is or how to change it.

Comment: Would you mind giving us the real file name? you can still use `mybucket` as the bucket. But as far as I know, the URL seems fine to me. `{bucket}.s3-{region}.amazonaws.com/{path}`

Comment: Are you receiving a cached version from an Edge location ? Does your  bucket's versioning configuration have MFA Delete ?